# ionos webhosting - how can i clear cache on the back-end?

Tags: caching, web-hosting, web-development-server, ionos

How can i clear the cache for a website on the back-end? I have performed this action before in the past thorugh IONOS however I cannot seem to find the option to repeat. I have my hosting through IONOS.com and have uploaded all my web files that I created using Webflow. I’ve tried searching through the hosting settings but cannot locate the option to clear the cache. I also cannot find any article about it online. Additionally – I cannot find any way to access cPanel through IONOS either. I used to be able to manage my files using cPanel but cannot recall if this is the way that I cleared the cache on the back-end previously.